# Passar mais de um parametro para outra pagina

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Estou fazendo uma aplicação windows phone, no qual na tela principal( primeira tela) é feito um calculo, e o resultado é exibido em uma segunda tela.

Ja consegui fazer a 'conexao' entre as duas telas da seguinte maneira

Na página 1 ou tela principal:

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Uri caminho = new Uri("/Paginas/Resolucao.xaml?parametro=" textBlock1.Text, UriKind.Relative);
        NavigationService.Navigate(caminho);

    }
```

Na Página 2 ou tela secundária

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string parametroRecebido1 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parametro"];
        textBlock2.Text = parametroRecebido1;       
    }
```

Porém com esses 'metodos' eu só conseguindo passar uma variavel( a variavel que fica no textBlock1)
Eu vi nesse site http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives no Option3 que para passarmos mais de uma variavel teria que ser feito o seguinte código:

Na página 1 ou tela principal;

```
    private void btnNavigate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?parameter1=p1& parameter2=p2",UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Na Segunda tela;

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
     string parameterValue1 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter1"];
     string parameterValue2 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter2"];  
    }
```

____ **A minha dúvida é seguinte** : como vou fazer para passar por exemplo as minha variaveis n1 e n2 no método da primeira tela

```
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?parameter1=p1&parameter2=p2", UriKind.Relative));
```

___ Eu tentei encaixar as minhas variaveis n1 e n2 nesta linha de código da seguinte maneira:  ---- Mas DEU ERRO

```
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?parameter1="+n1&+"parameter2=n2", UriKind.Relative));
```

___ Tentei também manter o código 'original' so modificando o nome das variaveis
Assim:

```
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?parameter1=n1&parameter2=n2", UriKind.Relative));
```

Porém na hora de exibir os resultados ele apenas exibiu a as palavras 'n1' e 'n2' e não os valores ali armazenado

Quem puder ajudar vou ficar imensamente grato :D

Comment: Diego, você errou apenas as "" no comando:     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?parameter1=" + n1 + "&parameter2=" + n2, UriKind.Relative)); - Prefira o string.Format para evitar esses problemas.

Comment: Malkaviano, deu certo aqui, não acredito que quebrei a cabeça por horas por causa de uma " , mas agora já sei. Obrigado aee 

Comment: Boa noite amigo não poste a reposta dentro da pergunta, não somos um fórum simples, somos um Q&A, portanto você pode responder a sua própria pergunta clicando no botão responder, além do mais não é necessário editar o título e escrever RESOLVIDO, ao marcar a resposta correta a questão já é considerada como resolvida. Uma boa noite

Comment: Amigo acho que você está confuso, eu disse no comentário anterior que escrever RESOLVIDO no título não é necessário.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  Fiquei um pouco confuso mesmo hahaha, mas acho que ja esta tudo certo, desculpe, é que comecei a pouco dias no forum

Comment: Justamente não somos fórum, somos uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas, aqui o esquema é mais organizado :) no início parece chato é difícil, mas a organização essa através da própria ferramenta tornam as comunidades stackexchange bem mais fácil de moderar e organizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o IsolatedStorageSettings para armazenar as variáveis antes de ir para a próxima tela.

Para armazenar:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings["parameter1"] = this.txtboxDescription;
settings["parameter2"] = this.txtboxDescription2;
settings.Save();
```

Para obter, depois que passou para a próxima página (NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml')):

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
string txtboxDescription2 = settings["parameter1"];
string txtboxDescription2 = settings["parameter2"];
```

Se não for string, você pode fazer um cast para o valor:

```
Boolean saveLogin = (bool)settings["saveLogin"];
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUÇÃO**

Fui informado pelo usúario https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/21504/malkaviano que meu erro havia sido apenas no uso das aspas("). Com o erro corrigido o código fica na seguinte maneira:

Tela principal ou primeira pagina

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Uri caminho = new Uri("/Paginas/Resolucao.xaml?parametro="+n1+"&parametro2="+n2, UriKind.Relative);
NavigationService.Navigate(caminho);

}
```

O meu erro foi separa o & das string e colocar ele fora das aspas(").

No caso n1 e n2 são minha variaveis;

Na Segunda Tela ficará assim:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    string parametroRecebido1 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parametro"]; 
    string parametroRecebido2 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parametro2"];


   textBlock1.Text = parametroRecebido1;
   textBlock2.Text = parametroRecebido2;

}
```

Caso queira também passar de 1 à quantas variaveis voce quiser voce fará da seguinte maneira: No caso vou exemplificar com três variaveis(n1,n2,n3)

Na Tela Principal

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Uri caminho = new Uri("/Paginas/Resolucao.xaml?parametro="+n1+"&parametro2="+n2+"&parametro3="+n3 UriKind.Relative);
NavigationService.Navigate(caminho);

}
```

Na segunda tela

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    string parametroRecebido1 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parametro"]; 
    string parametroRecebido2 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parametro2"];
    string parametroRecebido3 = NavigationContext.QueryString["parametro3"];

   textBlock1.Text = parametroRecebido1;
   textBlock2.Text = parametroRecebido2;
   textBlock3.Text = parametroRecebido3;

}
```